# MySQL: How to get the maximum disposition and the maximum date from my database

Tags: mysql, max

I want to get the top disposition of every ID where 1 is the lowest and 13 is the highest, however when there are IDs with similar disposition (e.g. ID #2 having multiple dispositions of '9') I cannot get the record with the latest time / timestamp.

How can I group the results by ID getting the maximum disposition and if there are multiple disposition, get the most recent? 
(e.g. ID #2 getting '2017-04-06 14:16:00' as the top or max.)

edit: 
I forgot to mention that I also need to group them by date. I have a separate column for date. The expected output is: Latest + Highest dispo of ID #2 on April 6 and Latest + Highest dispo of ID#2 on April 7 and so forth.

edit2:

[image]
[image]

Comment: See [_Groupwise Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've set up the next example:

> ```
> create table docs(id int, dispo int, dt date, st timestamp);
> ```

> ```
> insert into docs values
> (1, 10, '20170406', '2017/04/06 01:30:00'),
> (1, 5 , '20170407', '2017/04/07 02:30:00'),
> (1, 10, '20170406', '2017/04/06 01:00:00'),
> (1, 10, '20170406', '2017/04/06 01:15:00'),
> (2,  9, '20170406', '2017/04/06 01:30:00'),
> (2,  9, '20170407', '2017/04/07 13:45:00'),
> (2,  9, '20170407', '2017/04/07 09:00:00'),
> (2,  9, '20170407', '2017/04/07 10:45:00');
> ```

First you need to know the MAX disposition of every date:

> ```
> SELECT   id ID, dt "Date", max(dispo) Disposition
> FROM     docs
> GROUP BY id, dt
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Date       | Disposition
> -: | :--------- | ----------:
>  1 | 2017-04-06 |          10
>  1 | 2017-04-07 |           5
>  2 | 2017-04-06 |           9
>  2 | 2017-04-07 |           9
> ```

Then you can obtain MAX Stamp by disposition and date.

> ```
> SELECT   t1.id ID, 
>          t1.dispo Disposition, 
>          t1.dt "Date", 
>          max(t1.st) Stamp
> FROM     docs t1
> JOIN     (SELECT   id, dt, max(dispo) as dispo
>           FROM     docs
>           GROUP BY id, dt) t2
> ON        t1.id = t2.id
> AND       t1.dispo = t2.dispo
> AND       t1.dt = t2.dt
> GROUP BY  t1.id, t1.dispo, t1.dt
> ORDER BY  t1.id, t1.dt;
> ```
>
> ```
> ID | Disposition | Date       | Stamp              
> -: | ----------: | :--------- | :------------------
>  1 |          10 | 2017-04-06 | 2017-04-06 01:30:00
>  1 |           5 | 2017-04-07 | 2017-04-07 02:30:00
>  2 |           9 | 2017-04-06 | 2017-04-06 01:30:00
>  2 |           9 | 2017-04-07 | 2017-04-07 13:45:00
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=c51598421e49b51d08d782ea29b0a2e6)*

Comment: I forgot to mention that I also need to group them by date. I have a separate column for date. The expected output is: Latest + Highest dispo of ID #2 on April 6 and Latest + Highest dispo of ID#2 on April 7.

Comment: Please add a good  example in your question of your desired result.

Comment: Thank you for helping. I have provided a sample date for you to check.

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a correlated subquery to find the max timestamp...

```
select q1.id,
       q1.dispo,
       q1.date,
       (select max(stamp) from table_a where id=q1.id and dispo=q1.dispo and date=q1.date) as max_stamp
  from (select id, max(dispo) as dispo, date
          from table_a
         group by id, date) as q1;
```

And this approach uses a join...

```
select q1.id,
       q1.dispo,
       q1.date,
       max(a.stamp) as max_stamp
  from (select id, max(dispo) as dispo, date
         from table_a
         group by id, date) as q1
  join table_a a on (a.id=q1.id and a.dispo=q1.dispo as a.date=q1.date)
```